# UK standard Visa applying as family

Tags: standard-visitor-visas

I am from Pakistan and like to apply for UK visitor visa with family of 4. While making seperate application at gov.uk, and filling financial detail for family, it is not possible to write N/A as it need numbers. I am confused how to find a solution for this issue.
Waiting for your response,
Regards,